# Is there a fast way to correct color differences in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I'm using Photoshop CS6 and I just photographed about 50 different high polish objects.

Is there any way to correct the color and reflection in an easy way? the only way i know would be the copy-stamp and mend-tool (I hope they're called that in english, i just translated it from german)

with those tools it's a very expensive task. is there any tool which could make my life easier?

Here's a not yet corrected picture

[image]

here's what it should look like in the end (similar)

[image]

Some more example pictures:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Haven't forgotten this. The beige makes it a bit harder. Will you be cropping the items off the backgrounds or leaving the backgrounds in?

Comment: @Ryan backgrounds are getting cropped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a fun challenge but think I came up with a nice solution for you - added it to my video series if you'd like to see it in under a minute: https://youtu.be/GqLPVGHK08c

Basically I converted it to Lab color mode. Did a color overlay layer. Then did Layer Style Blending Options to pull out based on the amount of red and light in the underlying layer. Of course this step will differ with the products. Might need to pull out based on Yellow or Blue or whatever.

[image]

Comment: Is there any answer where you don't start by converting to Lab? ;-)

Comment: @Cai when I explain to people about pixelation :D

Comment: haha! touché :)

Comment: @Ryan that's the first time ever I get a whole video dedicated to my question :D! very nice solution, it's making my life so much easier. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the OP wants to "correct."

However, just today, I had a large amount of images that needed the white balance corrected in various ways. I tried the Filter/Camera Raw Filter and it did a really good job with the individual images.